# Fortran array allocating different size in different dimension

Tags: fortran

Could I allocate a 2D array like that? array(1,:) only have 5 elements and array(2,:) only have 3 elements?
What I can do is only like
allocate( array(2,5) )
but it allocates a 2*5 = 10 elements. Could I allocate 8 elements?

Comment: I just want to save spaces and avoid errors. But it seems like it does not work.

Comment: you cannot. FORTRAN is not a dynamic kind of language. To do that you would have to work with 1D array and a code of your own (ex: sparse matrix). Good luck!